# print results with high precision (floating point)

Tags: awk

I have 100 columns and 10000 rows, and want to subtract some number only from 4th column.

```
awk '{$4=$4-0.007797948600925214}{print}' t1 > t2
```

I tested with `$4=0`, and the answer is `-0.00779795`.

How can I use awk to get `-0.007797948600925214`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `float` formatting , example:

```
awk 'BEGIN{printf "%.18f", 0.007797948600925214}'
```

Check the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Floating_002dpoint-Programming.html).